# Sorting large files by [M]M/[D]D/YYYY

Tags: linux, sorting, date, date-sorting

I have these large tab-delimited text files that I want to sort by the date field (the 17th field). The issue is that the dates come in the format [M]M/[D]D/YYYY meaning that there are no leading zeros so dates can be:

3/3/2013,
4/17/2014,
12/4/2013

Is it possible to use the `sort` command to do this? I haven't been able to find an example that takes into account no leading zeros.

As a note, I've tried recalculating the date field to be days from a certain date and then sorting on that. This works but the read/write necessary to do this extra step takes a long long time.

Comment: What's the file format?

Comment: Consider writing a filter that converts from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd, then sort, then filter back to mm/dd/yyyy (omitting leading zeros, etc).  The `-k1.1,1.2n` type notation for subfields in the `sort` command breaks down with variable-width sub-fields.

Comment: Please show us 4-5 full lines.

Comment: its a tab delimited text file, there are more than 40 other fields along with it so I don't want to put that in here, but the date field is the 17th field if that helps

Comment: How big are the files? (ballpark)

Answer (score 0):

If the date is at the start of the line:

```
sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2
```

Use the --debug option to sort if available to help

Comment: Does the `-k` call out specific characters or fields separated by whitespace? The date is actually in the middle of the line. Is there a command to use to get to that field and then sort by the characters from the last / to the end of the field, then by from start of field to first / and finally by the numbers in between the /'s?

Comment: @StSh, Fields separated by `/`, as per `-t`.

Comment: ah gotcha, unfortunately the date isn't at the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

The following prefixes each lines with YYYYMMDD before passing it to `sort`, then removes the added characters.

```
<file.in perl -pe'
   $_ = (
      m{^(?:[^\t]*\t){16}(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\t}
         ? sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $3, $1, $2)
         : " " x 8
   ) . $_;
' | sort | cut -b 9- >file.out
```

Comment: I'm super new to this sort of stuff; would I run this as a shell script? Would this be significantly faster than using read/write in python?

Comment: It's a `bash` shell command. You could put it in a file if you want. Or not. /// In theory, it should be the same. In practice, you'll have to try it and find out.